# OutOfMemory during paging

Tags: asp.net

I am using ObjectDataSource, ListView, CustomPaging

If the total number of rows is too big, I got OutOfMemory exception, it seems that it caused by some array, I don't get it, because total number of rows should never make any array to be filled with elements, the page size do!!

This is the logger.

************EXCEPTION # 3 : 4/30/2010 9:43:07 PM
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.get_Controls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(ArrayList childState)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\flickrdemo\15752207\c63ea96c\App_Web__8yxn9sb.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

---

Comment: what do you call "too big"? 100? 1000? 100000000?

Comment: Make sure you don't have an endless loop or some recursive call that doesn't end properly.

Comment: it is 100000000 and if there is an endless loop why it work well with smaller data

Comment: And this is an array of 100,000,000 what kind of items ? Why are you allocating an array of 100M ?

Comment: If you answered your own question then accept the answer and close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now, it seems that Behind the sense ObjectDataSource is creating an array with the size of Total rows, which in this case too big, I know that because

1- DataPager is rendering the number of pages based on Datasource.
2- There is big array created.
3- and no, there is no big data retrieved just 15 elements.

I cannot verify this explanation, but I put a limit to a total count as working around.

Comment: Don't put a band aid. It will come back and bite you. Post some sample code here and we might be able to help. The ODS should not be creating an array of size total record count.